# SQLAlchemy can't adapt type for TextField

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms

For a Flask app, in my model I have the following field:

```
additional_notes = db.Column(db.Text)
```

In my form, I have the following:

```
additional_notes = TextField(u'Additional Notes')
```

When I attempt to save the form, it throws the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'TextAreaField' [SQL: 'UPDATE part SET make=%(make)s, identification_notes=%(identification_notes)s, additional_notes=%(additional_notes)s WHERE part.id = %(part_id)s'] [parameters: {'make': 'xToyotaasdf', 'identification_notes': , 'additional_notes': , 'part_id': 5}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Is there some sort of setting I need to make at the model level or the form level to connect the form field to this model field? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried parsing `additional_notes` to `str` before persisting into db?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're getting the data from the form, and not the form object itself. So in your routes, you should have something like:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
   model = Model(additional_notes=form.additional_notes.data)
   db.session.add(model)
```